# Nexentastor CE on Supermicro X10DRL-I

Tags: installation, zfs, supermicro, nexenta

I'm writing here because after 3 hours i'm still not able to install NexentaStorCE on my brand new server.
The hardware configuration is:
Supermicro x10drl-i
Xeon E5 2609V3
16GB DDR4 Kingston

I'm trying to install from an external usb cd-rom.
Unfortunately while booting the setup, just after the grub menu selection it stops with a wall of text of errors (and i'm unable to view the first lines)

How can we debug the situation?
I haven't any log and i'm unable to scroll up the console output...
Any ideas?[image: wall of errors on first boot]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

***Don't use NexentaStor for new installations in 2015. It's a dead product!!***

You could [post a support question on their forums](http://www.nexentastor.org/projects/site/boards/1) (*good luck*), but the community user base was basically abandoned and there are simply better alternatives for a [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) storage appliance. The main reason to consider this advice is [hardware support](http://juku.it/en/sorry-nexenta-but-i-dont-get-it-and-questions-arise/). Linux and other actively-developed operating systems can keep up with hardware innovations a bit better than a closed platform like NexentaStor.

Look at:

- [QuantaStor](http://www.osnexus.com/storage-appliance-os/)
- [Zetavault](http://www.dnuk.com/zetavault/intro/)
- [OmniOS](http://omnios.omniti.com)
- [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org)
- [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org)
- [ZFS on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org)

Answer (score 0):

Usb cdrom installation is not supported. You may use sata cdrom.